# How to update a Borland 6 C++ Project from including indy.bpi to indy60.bpi?

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy, bpl

I develop with Borland Builder 6 in C++.
And when I click on "Components" / "Installer des paquets",
I see the Package dclIndy60.bpi : "Internet Direct (Indy) for D6 Property and Component Editors", meaning for me that it's all ok, I use as wished the Indy60 package (in an Indy9 folder : version 9 for indy dated of november 2002) and no longer use the old "indy" package (default version on my BCB6 install disc).

My problem is that I try to compile an "old_project", apparently coded using the old Indy.bpi package (instead of Indy60 in mine) and during the compilation it pops a window saying : "impossible to find the 'paquet d'importation' : indy.bpi", with a browse button; I thence browse to the only "indy" bpi file i have : Indy60.bpi.

In fact I have reinstalled successfully (as seems) indy9, taking care first to remove every trace of the old indy (as advised on forums) and the wished indy 9 before installing again indy 9 (using the BCB 6 disc to remove the old indy).
And in my "old_project" I have made sure (as said above) that it points to indy60 in the "component" menu.
But at compiling time, it still asks for "indy.bpi".

=> How is it possible to remove any reference to this old indy.bpi and/or replace it with the new "indy60.bpi" ?

=> Or do I misunderstand badly the difference between indy.bpi and indy60.bpi ?
or do I make a too great confusion in my management of bpi and bpl for Borland Builder ?

=> Or would I have better create a new project and copy in it file by file from the old BCB C++ project ?

Sorry for the confusions I can make, I'm a little bit new to developping C++ application from scratch (having 3 years experience in maintaining allready written applications) and new too to Borland Builder.

Best regards,
Arnaud.

Comment: Here is a list of the bpi and bpl and lib file containing "Indy60" or "Indy"(none) present on my computer :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects\Bpl\Indy60.bpl
\MyDevIncludeDirectory\Indy60.lib
\MyDevIncludeDirectory\Indy60.bpi
\MyDevIncludeDirectory\dclIndy60.bpl

Comment: Ok I roughly copied Indy.bpi from another computer.
The compile process does not ask any more for "indy.bpi" (at least, up to where it achieves compiling)

Comment: => I now have "unresolved external" destuctors in .obj files :
I wrote it on another question thread :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118115/unresolved-external-in-obj-files-concerning-freetype-library-class-destructors-t

=> But can anybody explain me the indy.bpi / indy60µ.bpi issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the project's .bpk file in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) or other text editor. You can then change the package references as needed.

Comment: Ok thanks as said above I eventually copied the indy.bpi from somewhere else. But I'll try to correct the bpk in Notepad if the internet components tell me raw words.